# label on top of bar . How to draw like this?

Tags: tikz-pgf, overleaf

[image][image]

Please help to write code for this .

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SX. This site is not a free support site, so in questions like this one, you should provide a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) showing what you tried. If you have no idea where to start, you should have a look at a TikZ tutorial, and then come back here with questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

Code (adapt the coordinates to Yours data):

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}  
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \filldraw[cyan!20](-1,1) rectangle (8,-5);
        \node at (4,.5) (b) {\bfseries \large Visit to museums in 2022};
        \node at (4,.1) (b) {\bfseries (in millions)};
        \foreach \i/\t/\d in {1/Firt Item/5.5,2/Second Item/4.8,3/Third Item/3.7,4/Fourth Item/2.5}{%
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\j}{100-10*\i};
            \node[anchor=west] at (.1,-\i+.2) (a\i) {\bfseries  \t};
            \filldraw[blue!\j] (0,-.5-\i) rectangle (\d,-\i) node[pos=.5,white] () {\bfseries \d};
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}  
\end{document}
```

Comment: can we add 2nd bar with same name in different colour . two bar for each item.?

Comment: I dont understand. Can you add a hand sketch?

Comment: added hand sketch ,Thanks

Comment: Please check hand sketch which is attached in main section.

Comment: This is another question.

Comment: can't  we just have to add one line ,i tried but it was showing error

Comment: should i post it as a new question ?

Comment: Yes. The better is to try yourself ro answer to your question. My answer to your is complete!

Comment: i tried .. can even post new question .

Comment: You dont are happy with my first answer? I have the second ready, but if You dont agree...

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}  
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \filldraw[cyan!10](-1,2) rectangle (8,-8);
        \node at (3.4,1.5) (b) {\bfseries \large Visit to museums in \color{blue}{2022} \color{black}{and} \color{red}{2021}};
        \node at (3.4,1) (b) {\bfseries (in millions)};
        \foreach \i/\t/\d/\dr in {1/Firt Item/5.5/3.5,2/Second Item/4.8/3.6,3/Third Item/3.7/3,4/Fourth Item/2.5/2}{%
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\j}{100-10*\i};
            \node[anchor=west,violet] at (.1,{-2*(\i-1)+.2}) (a\i) {\bfseries  \t};
            \filldraw[blue!\j] (0,{-.5-2*(\i-1)}) rectangle (\d,{-2*(\i-1)}) node[pos=.5,white] () {\bfseries \d};
            \filldraw[red!\j] (0,{-1.2-2*(\i-1)}) rectangle (\dr,{-.7-2*(\i-1)}) node[pos=.5,white] () {\bfseries \dr};
        }
        \node[violet,rotate=90] at (-.5,-3) () {\Large \bfseries Events};
        \node[violet] at (4,-7.8) () {\Large \bfseries Quantity};
    \end{tikzpicture}  
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

I answer to js bibra with a graph (is better than my English) and put in y formulas \i=1,\i=2,...,\i=4:

[image]

Comment: I would like to learn how to code the syntax for the filldraw statement of the red and blu columns— I mean how did you come up with  ‘(0,{-.5-2*(\i-1)}) rectangle (\d,{-2*(\i-1)})’

Comment: @ js bibra Look at my update.

Comment: Seen - actually I wanted to learn how exactly did you come up with the formula within brackets (0,{-.5-2*(\i-1)}) rectangle (\d,{-2*(\i-1)}) - expansion of the foreach expression is quite clear—only not clear how did you originate the formula-.5-2(I-1) onwards

Comment: @js bibra You have:
\i=1 : (0,-.5) rectangle (5.5,0);
\i=2: (0,-2.5) rectangle (4.8,-2);
\i=3: (0,-4.5) rectangle (3.7,-4);
\i=4: (0,-6.5) rectangle (2.5,-6);
Each rectangle has one tall equal to 0.5.
Hi hope this fix the problem. Enjoy little maths!